# python path in git bash

Tags: python, path, git-bash

I am trying to download and build NS3 with git and using `bake`.

The problem is that I get this error:

```
$ ./bake.py configure -e ns-3.29
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the executable python in my python folder to python3 and it worked

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please be more specific about exactly what changes you made.

Comment: Apparently the Python 2.x executable (*python*) was changed to the Python 3.x executable (*python3*).